# Why is that variables and hierarchy is not supported in css by default?

Tags: html, css

I am somewhat new to UI development, but I am very much uncomfortable with how CSS actually works.

My use-case : [ Attempted with css & less ]

I wanted to apply some specific styles inside a particular `div` on a page.

**css attempt :**

```
div.class1 {
    font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-color: #f30;
}
div.class1 div.class2 {
    border: 1px solid #f30;
}
```

**less attempt :**

```
@red: #f30;
@font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
div.class1 {
    font: normal 12px @font-family;
    font-color: @red;
    div.class2 {
        border: 1px solid @red;
    }
```

- Now, writing css can induce bugs since it forces you to repeat `#f30` & `div.class2` everytime you try to achieve hierarchy and variable re-use.

**My Question :**

- Why is that css makes things difficult ?
- less does nothing special - just makes obvious improvements and translates to css ?
- What is that css wants to motivate in users because of which it promotes such a redundant coding style ?

**I strongly believe css should be what less is. Definitely I am overlooking some obvious advantage of why things are done that way in css.**

I thought it was a legacy problem, but I was surprised when I saw no attempts to solve this with css3.

Please help me understand how should I approach css ?

Comment: A strong viewpoint against variables: http://www.w3.org/People/Bos/CSS-variables. And on the other side of things, a spec for variables: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/

Comment: Got the answer : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/185039/40960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css is an old language and it takes a very long time for obscolete user agents to become unpopular enough for developper to stop supporting them. I don't see a major change in css happening for years.

Plus, i believe css and html were first attended to be really for people unfamiliar with programming languages.

Comment: Well, google is doing so many fundo stuff with javascript (V8). Why can't we support the new coding styles(features) in css - also maintaining the support for the old coding styles. People do css all day in the most famous websites, I suppose its still relevant.

Comment: Got the answer : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/185039/40960